# angular monitor DOM change outside angular's realm

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is [the jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/nohavikafa/6/edit?html,console,output),

I want to use regular DOM API manipulation and feed it back to angular.

The result is if using $timeout, it works. but not window.setTimeout. I know it is not the right way to deal with angular.  but in 3rd party component case, it makes sense to allow the 3rd party non angular developer to use pure vanilla or jquery to change the angular generated DOM attribute to get expected result.

How could we watch or observe the attribute change and update angular scope?

I found a hacky way to make it work by adding this line. `$interval(function(){$(el).attr('info');},2000)`, you could comment it out in jsbin to see the expected behavior.

But it's not quite what i want. any better solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, Angular doesn't know that there is a change if you are outside the Angular context, so you need to tell Angular that something has changed.

One of the thing, you are already using is the `$timeout` service. But there is an another a cleaner solution for this.

The place where you are using jQuery to change the DOM, you can call tell angular to fix things:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector("body")).scope().$apply();
```

`$apply()` method call be trigger digest cycle manually which Angular does on it's own when you work inside Angular context.

Comment: we definitely do not want to use angular's implicit $digest way to do so.  That's why i conclude to do my own dirty checking using $interval. As i mentioned just too dirty.